# A non-noetherian ring with all localizations noetherian

Tags: commutative-algebra

If for a ring $A$ every localization $A_\mathfrak{p}$ by a prime $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq A$ is noetherian, is it true that $A$ is noetherian?

I believe not but I can't find a good counterexample.

Comment: This Google search may be of interest: http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_algebraist_2005;task=show_msg;msg=2110.0001

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Recall that a ring is **Boolean** if every element is idempotent: for all $x \in R$, $x^2 = x$.  And in fact a Boolean ring is necessarily commutative.  Here are two further rather easy facts about Boolean rings (for proofs see e.g. Section 9 of [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf)):

1. A Boolean ring is Noetherian iff it is finite.
2. A Boolean ring is local iff it is a domain iff it is a field iff it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Combining these facts, one sees that any infinite Boolean ring -- e.g. the product of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ -- will be non-Noetherian but everywhere locally Noetherian.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't mind integral domains [this link](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5575531) might help. This is what I said there.

There do exist integral domains $D$ such that $D_M$ is a Dedekind domain
for every maximal ideal $M.$ These were called *almost Dedekind domains*
by Robert Gilmer in [Integral domains which are almost Dedekind](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1964-015-05/S0002-9939-1964-0166212-8/S0002-9939-1964-0166212-8.pdf), Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 15(1964) 813-818. That some of these domains are non-Noetherian is also indicated in the above reference. Note that (a) a Dedekind domain is Noetherian and (b) an almost Dedekind domain is a one dimensional Prüfer domain. (c) a domain $D$ is Prüfer if every finitely generated nonzero ideal of $D$ is invertible.
I hope this helps.

Muhammad